# LinkedHashMap: insert List of Strings

Tags: java, android

I have a LinkedHashMap and I want to insert a `List` of `String`s just to some of the 'headers' of my Expandable List, but for some reason I can't and I get the error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 1
```

```
LinkedHashMap <String, List<String>> expandableListDetail2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> category_header = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Producto> produtos;
        Database db = new Database(context);
        List<Categorias> categories;

        categories = db.getAllCategorias();

        for (int i=0; i<categories.size(); i++){

            expandableListDetail2.put(categories.get(i).toString(), category_header);

            produtos = db.getAllProductos(categories.get(i).toString());


               for(int j=0;j<produtos.size();j++) {
                   category_header.add(i, produtos.get(i).getNameProducto());
               }

        }
```

I'm getting error on the line where I have `category_header.add(...)` and all the products are been added to all keys. Can you help?

Comment: Nit: you don't need to have the conditional `if (produtos.size() > 0)` because the for loop checks it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is using `i` where you should use `j`

```
if (produtos.size() > 0) {
   for(int j=0;j<produtos.size();j++) {
       category_header.add(i, produtos.get(j).getNameProducto());
   }
}
```

Also it is not neccessary to have an extra `if (produtos.size() > 0) {` because if `produtos.size()` is zero the for loop will iterate zero times anyway.

Comment: No..because I want to insert my list of products a specific category. Not all categories have products...so I have 'i' to identify the correct category to insert my products. And changing it to j, as you said I also get the error.

Comment: @porthfind Surely you can't use `produtos.get(i).getNameProducto()` with index `i` beacuse that *will* cause an exception.

Comment: You are right, I though you were talking about first 'i' on the category_header.add. But even so I go on with the same error, with another index...Invalid index 10, size is 0

Comment: The problem is on "produtos.get(j).getNameProducto()" but I don't know why :\

Comment: @porthfind It could be in the `getNameProducto` function.